# PhpStorm Auto update code coverage data from Codeception

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

So I have `PhpStorm` installed on my computer and I'm of course loving it.

I usually run Tests with coverage and it updates on my UI instantly as soon as I do so. So far I liked how all these worked. But since few months, I moved away from `PHPUnit` to `Codeception`.

Now I'm unable to run tests. At least not how I used to. The actual test button doesn't work, so I've to create a run configuration which will run that file and I see the output on command line. It generates the `coverage.xml` file which I can load and see the coverage info on `IDE`, but I need to do so every time I run tests.

I tried googling around, tried to create a `PhpStorm` extension for Codeception, tried various plugins, but no luck. Now my current work flow looks like this:

- Run the tests with coverage (either from command line or using run configuration)
- Hit `Ctrl+Alt+6` (Coverage Suit to Display) and click on Show Selected Button
- See the updates and repeat this process.

What I'm exactly looking for is, is there some way that PhpStorm automatically detect the update of `coverage.xml` file and apply the new file. To do that, I searched a little bit I selected the option to

> Replace active suites with the new one

Please notice the following selection. But when I run the tests with coverage and `coverage.xml` file gets updated, it doesn't reflect. However with PHPUnit, it used to give me a button for running with coverage and it would update my Editor's UI reflecting the new coverage.

[image: Option selected]

Options I tried

- Create a plugin for PhpStorm (was a little difficult, I could create plugin, which worked in `IntelliJ IDEA` but it didn't work on PhpStorm, I did notice that we need to target PhpStorm or use ultimate version with PHP enabled, but didn't help much.
- Searching for plugins. (Didn't find anything)
- Intercept the calls to `PHPUnit` and convert them to `Codeception` (which was really hacky and this will be used in an organization so I don't want too hacky solution)

If anyone having gone through similar situation, any pointers would be great.

I really don't want to use `PHPUnit` since we have decided to use `Codeception` and going back is not an option.

Comment: 1) Actual Codeception support ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16350 2) Coverage auto-refresh: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-25513

Comment: Thanks, I did go to these links but after I posted the question, sorry I missed that. Codeception support ticket was created a long time ago, and I still see nothing. The auto refresh thing is not touched and needs discussion. How are you dealing with this? @LazyOne

Comment: I'm not using Codeception and I'm not using custom coverage reports (only PHPUnit which is run directly from IDE where it works OK).